# Login Password not Matching with database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

please could any one take a look at this code. I'm having issues with the login. this was what I did. I used the insert on phpmyadmin to insert mykard, password and salt. then go back to login with the same info in the database. but it keeps telling me wrong password...it looks like the password is encrypted.

```
function password_check($mykad, $input, $sql) {
    $passwordcheck = mysqli_fetch_array(
                            mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT password, salt FROM usersdb WHERE mykad='$mykad'"),
                            MYSQLI_NUM);
    if (crypt($mykad.$input, $passwordcheck[1]) == $passwordcheck[0])
        return true;
    else
       return false;
}

function password_salt_generator() {
    return '$2y$09$'.substr(str_shuffle(password_string_list()), 0, 22);
}

function password_string_list() {
    return '0123456789ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
}
```

Comment: You can first echo both the values before comparing them, so that you can see if the values are what you are expecting to have

Comment: thanks...but how do I do that...I'm still a beginner

Comment: As a beginner you probably should not be starting with password encryption, there are plenty of pre-rolled password classes out there that you can use. Once you have a better grasp of the language you could consider it, but even then personally I would still leave that to somebody who has a complete grasp of the subject.

Comment: actually got the code from github....

Comment: common..you mean no one would help me out with this issue....

Comment: I think this is the problem: you are checking in this control: crypt($mykad.$input, $passwordcheck[1]) == $passwordcheck[0] if the passwordCheck[0] cripted is equals to passwordCheck[1] not cripted.why it should be like this? these are both password retrieved from the query . instead you should check if the password provided by the client CRIPTED is equals to the one on the database.

Comment: Good point....i will check it out now... Thanks

Comment: "actually got the code from github". Ok but that doesn't mean you should trust it. Anyone can put stuff on GitHub. This code does have another problem - it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL as you have done with the $mykad variable. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: Oh.. Great...thanks too

Comment: I'm stil having issues with this code...just want to make sure the admin can log in safely...how to I get ride of this encryption

Comment: Thanks guys I have been able to fix it... Really appreciate all your comment and support..onelove